# Objects of multiple class in java

Tags: java

I was revising some of the old school concepts of Java in order to solve one problem . I have written the following code where i am trying the create objects of multiple class in that same classes and calling the methods with those objects from the main.

```
class a {
    public void display() {
        System.out.println("inside class a");
        a a1= new a();
    }
}

class b {
    public void display() {
        System.out.println("inside class b");
        b b1= new b();
    }
}

public class one {
    void display() {
        System.out.println("inside class one");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        one o = new one();
        a1.display();
        b1.display();
        o.display();
    }
}
```

I am getting object cannot be resolved error. My question is what i need to change to let the above code work. And, do i need to always declare objects inside the main().

Any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: the _scope_ of `a1` and `b1` are only visible in their containing methods. you should create the objects within the main method and it should be fine.

Comment: Right, Can we make it visible to the class one where the main method resides?Actually i dont want to create their objects in main

Comment: `a1` & `b1` must be declared and instantiated inside the main.

Comment: You haven't even created an object of `a` or `b` in `main`.  
Why do you expect the code of display that creates such objects to even be called, and why do you expect then to be accessible from `main`?  

It is not clear why you want to create a1 and b1 from within display.

Comment: i want to know is it possible to create object of any class in that class's method and to call it from main.i know i can create it from main @yuval

Comment: It's strange that an instance of `b` creates another instance of `b` (in the method `display()`. I think you might want to [read a little more about objects and classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/). Oh and stick to the Java Naming Conventions. Classes **must** start with an uppercase letter.

Comment: My question was is it possible to create an object of an class in the same class and call it from main?

Comment: @newuser Yes and no:  
1. Yes you can create an object of the class within a function of itself (just not in the constructor as it will cause an infinite loop of constructors).  
2. No you won't have access to the object you just created from anywhere outside that function, unless you return if.  

Also, in order to call that function, you first have to create an object of that type, unless the function is static,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really sure why you would want to do that, but assuming you're just wondering about the possibility to implement such a thing - yes, it can be done.

You can create an instance of a class inside that same class, like so:

```
public class A {
    public static A instance = new A();

    public void display() {
        System.out.println("inside class A");
    }
}
```

Pay attention to the `static` modifier in the above code; it allows you now to access `instance` from another place (class, method, `main`) like so:

```
A.instance.display();
```

If you want to know whether you can declare a variable inside a **method**, and not a class, and make it accessible from another method, then the answer is - no, you cannot.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to declare objects inside the ***main()***

```
class a {
    public void display() {
        System.out.println("inside class a");
    }
}

class b {
    public void display() {
        System.out.println("inside class b");
    }
}
public class one {
    void display() {
        System.out.println("inside class one");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        a a1= new a();
        b b1= new b();
        one o = new one();
        a1.display();
        b1.display();
        o.display();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what you want to achieve and yes you should create object of class a and class b inside main functions to use instance methods of these classes.

```
package com.stack.overflow;

    class a
    {
        public void display()
        {
            System.out.println("inside class a");
            //a a1= new a();   ---> No need of this line as you can 
   // directly access instance variables and methods directly without 
  // creating any object or you can also use **this** keyword for the same
        }
    }

    class b
    {
        public void display()
        {
            System.out.println("inside class b");
            //b b1= new b();  ---> No need of this line as you can 
   // directly access instance variables and methods directly without 
  // creating any object or you can also use **this** keyword for the same
        }
    }


    public class one 
    {
        void display()
        {
            System.out.println("inside class one");
        }
        public static void main(String[] args) {

            one o = new one();

            a a1=new a();
            b b1=new b();

            a1.display();
            b1.display();
            o.display();

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may find the answer to your confusion easily - *@ratul-sharker : `a1` & `b1` must be declared and instantiated inside the main.* as well as other answers here correcting your code.

The real question is your notion of scoping and lifetime of variables - Not only `a1` and `b1` lie inside the classes `a` and `b` but they have been instantiated inside methods so they are local. So, try to understand the difference between field variables and local variables - their lifetimes and scopes are vastly different.

Accessing a local variable directly like that(*which **will be** instantiated when the method is called*) is like asking asking for a result from future in the present. Note that field variables will remain as long as object is alive but the local variables will remain only for the duration of the method call.

Hope it is clear to you now.

Also, your question:

> My question was is it possible to create an object of an class in the
>   same class and call it from main?

Yes. Because main is a static method so it is not bound to an object like non-static method does. static methods are class level while non-static methods are object level. You can also create an instance in a non-static method for that matter.